# Horizontal zoom with D3 version 4?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

With D3 version 4, how do I restrict zoom to just the x axis?

Example with unrestricted zoom:

```js
var sideLength = 190;
var data = [
  [0, 0],
  [0.5, 0.8],
  [1, 0.4]
];
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", sideLength)
  .attr("height", sideLength);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([sideLength, 0]);
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, sideLength]);
var graphGroup = svg.append("g");
var onZoom = function() {
  graphGroup.attr("transform", d3.event.transform);
};
var zoomBehavior = d3.zoom().on("zoom", onZoom);
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  });

svg.call(zoomBehavior);
graphGroup.selectAll("path").remove();
graphGroup.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Zoom</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know what are you looking for exactly by "restrict zoom to just x axis" but if you mean you want y axis to remain untouched when zooming (and consequently your shapes to be distorted) you can manually build the transformation function.

`d3.event.transform` has 3 attributes `x`, `y` and `k` which are coordinates of zoom point and scale.

`d3.event.transform.toString` would give you a string like below:

`translate(x, y) scale(k)` and if you are familiar with transformations, you already know how to make your desired transformation. But FYI two parts of original transformation are:

`translate(x, y)`: The reason you fell zoom occurs at point mouse is pointing to. It actually moves the object so if you remove this part, canvas would scale about center.

`scale(k)` scales the canvas.

The trick is if you want y axis not to scale, you can pass additional arg to scale for y axis.

So if you just want y axis to be untouched (not scaled and not translated) you may have:

```js
var sideLength = 190;
var data = [
  [0, 0],
  [0.5, 0.8],
  [1, 0.4]
];
var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", sideLength)
  .attr("height", sideLength);
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([sideLength, 0]);
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear().range([0, sideLength]);
var graphGroup = svg.append("g");
var onZoom = function() {
var transform = d3.event.transform;
  var transformString = 'translate(' + transform.x + ',' + '0) scale(' + transform.k + ',1)';
  graphGroup.attr("transform", transformString);
};
var zoomBehavior = d3.zoom().on("zoom", onZoom);
var line = d3.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return xScale(d[0]);
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return yScale(d[1]);
  });

svg.call(zoomBehavior);
graphGroup.selectAll("path").remove();
graphGroup.append("path")
  .datum(data)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>D3 Zoom</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Do you know how to prevent distortion on the graphGroup? lines within look bad

Comment: @TomRoggero What do you mean? If you do not zoom across both x and y, shape aspect ratio would change.